# Экспорт таблицы easyui datagrid в xml(excel)

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, datagrid

Доброе утро. Использую такой код:

```
$.extend($.fn.datagrid.methods, {
toExcel: function(jq, filename){
  return jq.each(function(){
    var uri = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64,'
        , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
        , base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
        , format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) };

    var alink = $('<a style="display:none"></a>').appendTo('body');
    var view = $(this).datagrid('getPanel').find('div.datagrid-view');

    var table = view.find('div.datagrid-view2 table.datagrid-btable').clone();
    var tbody = table.find('>tbody');
    view.find('div.datagrid-view1 table.datagrid-btable>tbody>tr').each(function(index){
      $(this).clone().children().prependTo(tbody.children('tr:eq('+index+')'));
    });

    var head = view.find('div.datagrid-view2 table.datagrid-htable').clone();
    var hbody = head.find('>tbody');
    view.find('div.datagrid-view1 table.datagrid-htable>tbody>tr').each(function(index){
      $(this).clone().children().prependTo(hbody.children('tr:eq('+index+')'));
    });
    hbody.prependTo(table);

    var ctx = { worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.html()||'' };
    alink[0].href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
    alink[0].download = filename;
    alink[0].click();
    alink.remove();
  })
}});
```

Однако все равно при сохранении файла в ".xlsx" офис 2010 ругается на открытии файла. Если сменить тип файла на ".xls" и 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,', то xls прекрасно открывается. И еще проблема с кодировкой русских символов, кракозябры отображаются. Пытался вставить BOM-метку, но файл вообще не открывается в таком случае.

```
'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,' + '\uFEFF'
```

Как решить эти две проблемы?

Comment: Вы определитесь что вы хотите. 1. Почитайте формат biff8, скачайте спецификацию по xls (Excel 4,5,8).  2. Посмотрите как excel сохраняет в xml. 3. Поищите документацию на xlsx, распакуйте архив, просмотрите xml-ки, почитайте документацию на zip. Они чуть отличаются. Тогда у вас будет меньше вопросов:)

Comment: xlsx формат требует zip (deflate)-сжатие. Или хотя бы stored+zip. Скорее всего вы выгружаете в формате xml, который не есть xls и не есть xlsx. Что б убрать крякозябры, поставьте *кодировку* xml явно, попробуйте UTF-8 или `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>` (кодировка указывается в шапке). **Поставьте** в теме вопроса что выгружаете в xml(excel).

Comment: Я не досмотрел, вы используете html формат для excel, он так же не xls и xlsx! В 1251 кодировке всё ок, но скорее всего у вас utf-8. В *html* кодировка указывается meta-тегом. Добавьте в хедер кодировку  `<head><meta charset="utf-8" />`, укажите вашу (в примере кодировку не видно). И правильно запишите в вопросе какой формат используете.