# Как сохранить html таблицу в excel на js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

на сейте есть таблица при клике на кнопку она должна скачиваться в excel файл.

Нашел такой способ:

```
$('table.views-table.cols-7').click(function() {
  var url = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel.xls,' + encodeURIComponent($('table.views-table.cols-7').html())
  location.href = url
  return false
})
```

клик поставил на саму себя (не принципиально), но скачивается простой файл, не безо всякого расширения

какие атрибуты могут быть у этого файла и как их задать, ну то же название например. Есть ли какая то статья?

Comment: Возможно стоит воспользоваться для этого дополнительной библиотекой. Вот плагин для jquery https://github.com/rainabba/jquery-table2excel

Comment: Похожий вопрос недавно был, вот решение внутри вопроса http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/598022/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-easyui-datagrid-%D0%B2-xmlexcel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Файл нужно формировать на сервере а не на клиенте, а потом скачивать его. При помощи js клиентского не сделаете.

Comment: Не совсем так, неожиданно уже можно. С помощью data-протокола можно выгрузить хоть настоящий xsl или xslx файл (их сложно формировать на js, но можно:) ).  Остаётся проблема - сформировать файл. Тут есть два простых  метода xml+html, или xml+excel(его собственный). Один недостаток - получение файла по data-протоколу не работает для некоторых браузеров, в часности ie. Работает для опера фокс хром.

Comment: не проще ли выгрузить на сервере и скачать?